# Kafka with Node JS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

How can I integrate Kafka with Node JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kafka-node` npm is well documented - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

And here's a post to start with - 
https://thatcoder.space/getting-started-with-kafka-and-node-js-with-example/